# finding rows with one difference in DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data set were a number of rows are nearly identical, meaning they have the same values for all fields except column C.

```
    A    B         C     D ..... Z
0    50  'Ohio'   'Rep'  3       45
1    50  'Ohio'   'Dem'  3       45
2    40  'Kansas' 'Dem'  34      1
3    30  'Kansas' 'Dem'  45      2
4    55  'Texas'  'Rep'  2       7
....
38   55  'Texas'  'Dem'  2       7
```

I would like to identify all rows that are identical except for column C, but within column C I only want to to find combinations of 'Rep' and 'Dem'. So I don't want 2 identical rows with column C for instance being 'Rep' and 'Rep'.

```
     A    B         C   D ......Z
0    50  'Ohio'   'Rep'  3       45
1    50  'Ohio'   'Dem'  3       45
4    55  'Texas'  'Rep'  2       7
38   55  'Texas'  'Dem'  2       7
```

I have used the duplicated method on all columns (but C) and that provides all the rows that are identical. However, it does not lead to a duplication where each duplicated row with 'Rep' has exactly one duplicated row with 'Dem'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with the argument `keep`to `False`to create a mask for duplicated rows having dropped column `c` and use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to filter the rows that have any of `['Rep','Dem']`in them:

```
mask = df.drop(['C'], axis = 1).duplicated(keep=False)
df[mask][df['C'].isin(['Rep','Dem'])].drop_duplicates()

      A        B      C  D   Z
0  50   'Ohio'  'Rep'  3  45
1  50   'Ohio'  'Dem'  3  45
4  55  'Texas'  'Rep'  2   7
5  55  'Texas'  'Dem'  2   7
```

Comment: `isin` cannot be used here, because it select also  'Rep' and 'Rep'

Comment: True. I guess adding `drop_duplicates()` in the end solves it for the cases where there's only `Rep`and `Rep`in `c`?

Comment: From what I understand @Mike only wants rows that are identical except for column `c`, where two instances of `Rep` and `Dem`cannot be found, only one of each. So adding a `drop_duplicates`should solve it in my opinion. Thx for pointing out though!

Comment: OP need `I would like to identify all rows that are identical except for column C, but within column C I only want to to find combinations of 'Rep' and 'Dem'. So I don't want 2 identical rows with column C for instance being 'Rep' and 'Rep'`

Comment: Thanks guys. I only want them if for every 'Rep' there is also a 'Dem'. The current solution also finds rows with 2 'Dem' or 2 'Rep'

Answer (score 1):

Get all columns without `C` by [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) to list, then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) per column `C` and convert it to `tuples` per groups. Last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original, compare by `Rep,Dem` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['C']).tolist()

s = df.sort_values('C').groupby(cols)['C'].apply(tuple).rename('m') == ('Dem','Rep')
df = df[df.join(s, on=cols)['m']]
```

Another solution is compare by `set`s, but if possible because multiple same values per groups like `Rep,Dem,Dem` is possible chain condition with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html):

```
g = df.groupby(cols)['C']
m1 = g.transform('size') == 2
m2 = g.transform(lambda x: set(x) == set(['Rep','Dem']))

df = df[m1 & m2]
```

---

```
print (df)
     A        B    C  D   Z
0   50   'Ohio'  Rep  3  45
1   50   'Ohio'  Dem  3  45
4   55  'Texas'  Rep  2   7
38  55  'Texas'  Dem  2   7
```